# Photoshop - what version is best for a company new to in-house design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, software-recommendation

Our company does its own in-house design which is fairly new for the company.  We are wanting to now purchase a second licence for Photoshop.  Which version of Photoshop is best for company design work and what capabilities should the PC have in terms of graphic card, etc?  I'm afraid our IT department is not very clued up with graphic design requirements at all and are possibly looking for a cheap entry option as opposed to a capable option for the business.

Comment: You need to ask the designer you are hiring what they want to use.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to a relatively modern computer, I recommend [**Photoshop CC 2014**](http://www.photoshop.com/products/photoshop) (the latest version of the program), because of its flexibility and support.

CC is subscription-based, so you pay monthly. All the programs are stored online, you can download them in any computer (a single license allows two installations, but only one device can be logged in at a time). Because everything is on the cloud, you also get more frequent patches and updates, sometimes with new features. Finally, and I found this really useful when working in a company, you can download 30 day trials for all Adobe products from the same launcher, and you can update your subscription to add those products permanently; the more you subscribe to, the cheaper it gets.

Regarding hardware, as I mentioned any *modern* computer can run Photoshop CC. Ideally, you will need around 8Gb RAM, but it can also run on 2GB. You can [see the list of requirements here](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/system-requirements.html).

> Intel® Pentium® 4 or AMD Athlon® 64 processor (2 GHz or faster)
>
> Microsoft® Windows® 7 with Service Pack 1, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1
>
> 2 GB of RAM (8 GB recommended)
>
> 2 GB of available hard-disk space for installation; additional free space required during installation
> (cannot install on removable flash storage devices)
>
> 1024x768 display
> (1280x800 recommended) with 16-bit color and 512 MB of VRAM (1 GB
> recommended)
>
> OpenGL 2.0–capable system
>
> Internet connection and
> registration are necessary for required software activation,
> validation of subscriptions, and access to online services.

Answer (score 1):

There are only 2 options for Photoshop --

- Pay Adobe a monthly subscription and get the current release version
- Find version CS6 or older either used (with correct Adobe License transfers) or as old stock some retailer has lying around.

Your choices for obtaining Photoshop (legally) are not that broad.

As for hardware, as @Yisela points out, there are system requirements. Simply meet those as a *minimum*.